# Angular preserveWhitespaces : true / false , changes the layout in application

Tags: angular

We have an Angular application that generates custom components dynamically.

Components are rendered properly, but with the default configuration of angular (**preserveWhitespaces : true**) we have undesired "spaces" between our rendered components. When we set this config to **false**, those spaces disappear (they are the exact same components with the exact same style).

Why is that, why does the layout change because of whitespaces ? We know it's not related to css because no css was involve (the plunker has no css involve too).

We are using the latest version of angular 4.4.6

Here's a raw example of this behaviour :

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <div>
      <strong>preserveWhiteSpaces : false</strong>
      <preserve-whitespace-false></preserve-whitespace-false>
      <br>
      <strong>preserveWhiteSpaces : true</strong>
      <preserve-whitespace-true></preserve-whitespace-true>
    </div>
  `,
  preserveWhitespaces: false
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'preserve-whitespace-false',
  template: `
    <div>
      <custom-element></custom-element>
      <custom-element></custom-element>
    </div>
  `,
  preserveWhitespaces: false
})
export class PreserveWhiteSpaceFalseComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'preserve-whitespace-true',
  template: `
    <div>
      <custom-element></custom-element>
      <custom-element></custom-element>
    </div>
  `,
  preserveWhitespaces: true
})
export class PreserveWhiteSpaceTrueComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-element',
  template: `<span>custom-element</span>`,
})
export class CustomElementComponent {
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App,CustomElementComponent,PreserveWhiteSpaceTrueComponent,PreserveWhiteSpaceFalseComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and here's the plunker :

https://plnkr.co/edit/y5PwvRnPukDk35RwKTSJ?p=preview

Thank you !

Comment: I don't really understand. Ine one case, angular preserves the white spaces, so a white space is present between the components, whereas in the other case, it removes the white spaces, and there is thus no white space anymore between the components. Just as, if you remove the white space in "foo bar", it becomes "foobar". What exactly is surprising?

Comment: there's no differences in the 2 implementations, and we don't explicitly have a space in the code. preserveWhiteSpaces is meant for code optimization ? How is this suppose to change the layout when no modification to the html in the templates has happenned neither css ? Why the rendering is not the same ?

Comment: *we don't explicitly have a space in the code*: yes, you have plenty of white spaces: your first `</custom-element>` is followed by a line break, then by 6 white spaces, then by the second `<custom-element>`

Answer (score 0):

To put an explicit space in this is currently the best I've come up with:

```
{{ ' ' }}
```

Easy to search for too - if there's ever more options for preserve whitespace.

You can even put it on its own line like this:

```
<div *ngIf="address.countryCode == 'US'">
    <span>{{ address.city }}</span>
    {{ ' ' }}
    <span>{{ address.stateCd }}</span>
    {{ ' ' }}
    <span>{{ address.zipOrPostal }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a better option now for newer angular version. Using &ngsp;   similar to nbsp, but with 'ng'.

Comment: @Urielzen You should add this as a separate answer

Comment: Tried @Urielzen's tips on using &ngsp; on Angular 5, doesn't work

Comment: @Henry That is strange, according to the angular source code, it was introduced in 5.0.0-beta.4 https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/d2c0d986d44f3a7a29bdeacbe973a5550f5c6839#diff-fc39bbe62dc11ea559c60cff63c244d1

Comment: @Simon_Weaver I don't think the author of the question was actually wondering how to add explicit spaces but I feel like the issue was already addressed by the comments under the question.